# how to run Outlook add-in on send code sample on localhost

Tags: node.js, outlook, office-js

The third step of the code sample(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) procedure says

> 3.Deploy the add-in files to a directory on your web server. The files to upload are app.js and index.html.

but please tell me how to run it on localhost instead of the web server.
I get an error when I run npm start.

Comment: Most probably you first need to call the `npm install` to install dependencies.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I could run it in Outlook on the web, but not in Outlook on the desktop. Is there a difference between the web and desktop?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is your originally posted question answered?

Comment: 1.Open the file downloaded with vscode.
2.In terminal, go to the folder with package.json and run npm install and run npm start.
3.The Edge browser starts and https: // localhost: 3000 opens and "This Page is left blank intentionally" is displayed.
4.Open Outlook on the web and install Add Custom Add-in-Add from File contoso Message Body Checker.xml contoso Subject and cc Checker.xml
5.When I send a message with outlook on the web, [checked] is added to the title of the received email, and the address specified in cc is added.

Comment: 6.When I try to send a message with outlook on the desktop, the contoso Subject and cc Checker is still running and the transmission is not completed.

Comment: Windows and Outlook versions meet the requirements set.

Comment: Windows 1909,　Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft365 MSO(16.0.14228.20158) 64bit  Outlook version 2107(build 14228.20186) Latest Channel (preview)

Comment: Outlook on the desktop displays the message "Contoso message Body Checker could not be completed. Please try sending this message later."

Comment: I was able to run this sample from localhost. I believe this particular sample doesn't use NPM and works off the static files (which were working for you in OWA). For Win32 specifically, there's a good chance you need to enable the [local loopback exception](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost) for loading an add-in for localhost. If you'd like to create a simple taskpane add-in using [yo office](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office), it may give you a better error for why the add-in isn't loading from localhost.

Comment: We also just updated the GitHub sample to fix an unrelated issue (which you might encounter after resolving the localhost issue), so when you have a chance, please update your copy of the repo.